# Somfony CollectionType: Influces of ID, Name + DOM position on sort order?

Tags: forms, symfony

I am working on a `Symfony 3.4` based project and wonder what influence the `id` and `name` attributes of `CollectionType` form elements, as well as their position within the `DOM` have on the sort order.

I was not able to find anything about this in the documentation. My tests show that only the `name` is important but I would like to confirm this to not break anything.

---

**Details:**

- Assume we have a very simple `ToDoItem` entity with only two properties `date` and `value`.
- A `CollectionType` should be used to let the user edit a list of these items within a form.
- The form allows to remove existing items, add new items and to re-order the items using JS

The DB might contain the following items:

```
id    date          value
0     2020-06-01    do something
2     2020-06-02    do nothing
```

This would be rendered to a form like this:

```
...
<ul>
    <li id="todo_items_0>
        <input type="text" id="todo_items_0_date" name="todo[items][0][date]" value="2020-06-01">
        <input type="text" id="todo_items_0_value" name="todo[items][0][value]" value="do something">
    </li>
    <li id="todo_items_1>
        <input type="text" id="todo_items_1_date" name="todo[items][1][date]" value="2020-06-01">
        <input type="text" id="todo_items_1_value" name="todo[items][1][value]" value="do nothing">
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

**Test Result 1:**

Changing the **DOM order** has **NO effect** on the sort / DB order

```
...
<ul>
    <li id="todo_items_1>
        <input type="text" id="todo_items_1_date" name="todo[items][1][date]" value="2020-06-01">
        <input type="text" id="todo_items_1_value" name="todo[items][1][value]" value="NEW VALUE 1">
    </li>
    <li id="todo_items_0>
        <input type="text" id="todo_items_0_date" name="todo[items][0][date]" value="2020-06-01">
        <input type="text" id="todo_items_0_value" name="todo[items][0][value]" value="NEW VALUE 0">
    </li>
</ul>

// Result
id    date          value
0     2020-06-01    NEW VALUE 0
2     2020-06-02    NEW VALUE 1
```

---

**Test Result 2:**

Changing the **id** has **NO effect** on the sort / DB order

```
...
<ul>
    <li id="todo_items_1>
        <input type="text" id="todo_items_1_date" name="todo[items][0][date]" value="2020-06-01">
        <input type="text" id="todo_items_1_value" name="todo[items][0][value]" value="NEW VALUE 0">
    </li>
    <li id="todo_items_0>
        <input type="text" id="todo_items_0_date" name="todo[items][1][date]" value="2020-06-01">
        <input type="text" id="todo_items_0_value" name="todo[items][1][value]" value="NEW VALUE 1">
    </li>
</ul>

// Result
id    date          value
0     2020-06-01    NEW VALUE 0
2     2020-06-02    NEW VALUE 1
```

**BUT:** Changing the id might have other side effects. For example I am using a `jQuery Datepicker` which does not work anymore when the `id` is changed.

---

**Test Result 3:**

Changing the **name** **DOES** change sort / DB order.

```
...
<ul>
    <li id="todo_items_0>
        <input type="text" id="todo_items_0_date" name="todo[items][1][date]" value="2020-06-01">
        <input type="text" id="todo_items_0_value" name="todo[items][1][value]" value="NEW VALUE 0">
    </li>
    <li id="todo_items_1>
        <input type="text" id="todo_items_1_date" name="todo[items][0][date]" value="2020-06-01">
        <input type="text" id="todo_items_1_value" name="todo[items][0][value]" value="NEW VALUE 1">
    </li>
</ul>

// Result
id    date          value
0     2020-06-02    NEW VALUE 1
2     2020-06-01    NEW VALUE 0
```

While this does work in my case one should note, that this actually does not change the sort order but the order of the elements in the DB while keeping the `id` the same. So `Entity 0` now contains the information about item1 and `Entity 1` the information about item2...

---

**Conclusion:**

- The sort order within the `CollectionType` field is only effected by the `name` attribute
- Changing the `id` attribute or the DOM position has no effect.
- It seems to be no problem if `id` and `name` attributes represent different indexes.

**So the big question is:** Is this the intended Symfony behaviour which is documented somewhere or is this only an unintentional result which could change with any new Symfony release?

Answer (score 0):

The default order of a collection is by id but the order can be overwritten. I would add a position value to your ToDoItem and change that with JQuery to reoder the Collection. Your current solution is more of a hack and you should not keep using it.

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity=ToDoItem::class)
 * @OrderBy({"position" = "ASC"})
 */
private $toDoItems;
```

Comment: Why an explicit `sortOrder` field could of course be used, this is not really an answer to the question. Symfony does (somehow) creates a sort order from the submittted form data. As described in the question my test show that only the `name` field seems to influce this order. The question is, is this some whanted / documented feature or just a coincident which could change with every new release.

Comment: When a form is submitted the posted data is an array ['field_name' => 'field_value']. The id is ignored. When you change the names the data gets submitted in a different order and matched to other ToDoItem entities. This works for you but would create trouble if using versioning for tracking entity changes.